# i am using google o auth 2 for sign up in my application but after successful login if refresh page i am getting this error, can someone tell me

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, passport-google-oauth

TokenError: Bad Request
at OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (C:\Users\server\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:373:12)
at OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (C:\Users\server\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:420:16)
at C:\Users\server\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:177:45
at C:\Users\server\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:196:18
at passBackControl (C:\Users\server\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\server\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:530:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

and even after clearing the cookies if i hit the end point its directly redirecting to successful callback..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.